# How can I handle multiple file upload requests in the right way?

Tags: nginx, go, file-upload, digital-ocean, aws-sdk-go

Working on a project which has lots of image upload. And every image gets resized and thumbnailed.

At first I've tried to handle the upload of all images with a single request and when I test it in the server it gave Response Timeout Error.

Now I send request for each file to be uploaded and this seems to be slowing down the server.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

My code:

```
func SavePhotoWithBuffer(bigBuf, thumbBuf bytes.Buffer, bigSize, thumbSize int64, fileName, contentType string) {
    params := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:        aws.String("bucket"),
        Key:           aws.String(fileName),
        Body:          bytes.NewReader(bigBuf.Bytes()),
        ACL:           aws.String("public-read"),
        ContentLength: aws.Int64(bigSize),
        ContentType:   aws.String(contentType),
    }
    thumbParams := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:        aws.String("bucket"),
        Key:           aws.String("t_" + fileName),
        Body:          bytes.NewReader(thumbBuf.Bytes()),
        ACL:           aws.String("public-read"),
        ContentLength: aws.Int64(thumbSize),
        ContentType:   aws.String(contentType),
    }
    UploadWithParams(params, thumbParams)
}

//I've used github.com/patrickmn/go-cache package to cache the session.
func Open() *s3.S3 {
    var cachedData = cacheservice.GetCache("s3session")
    if cachedData == nil {
        var sess *s3.S3
        accessKey := "accessKey"
        secretKey := "secretKey"
        token := ""
        cred := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(accessKey, secretKey, token)
        _, err := cred.Get()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("bad credentials: %s", err)
        }
        conf := aws.NewConfig().WithRegion("eu-west-1").WithCredentials(cred)
        conf.Endpoint = aws.String("ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com")
        sess = s3.New(session.New(), conf)
        cacheservice.SetCache("s3session", sess)
        return sess
    }
    return cachedData.(*s3.S3)
}


func UploadWithParams(params, thumbParams *s3.PutObjectInput) {
    var se = Open()
    var err error
    _, err = se.PutObject(params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("bad response: %s", err)
    }
    _, err = se.PutObject(thumbParams)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("bad response: %s", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "It seems to be slowing down the server" mean?

Comment: While users are uploading images (like 150 images in a minute) server response time is very slow and the uploading process is slower than usual.

Comment: I don't think there's any need in using a "cache service" for the s3 session, just keep a global handy, exported as a variable or unexported and returned by Open. It's just added complexity for no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: If you don't already, run the upload in the background using a goroutine, your functions don't seem to return any values so there's no reason to wait for them to finish.

Comment: Lastly, but most importantly, the slowdown could be caused by a multitude of factors. You should first keep profiling your program until you can exactly identify the bottleneck and when you do but you're still unable to fix it you come back, update the question with your findings, and maybe someone will be able to help.

Comment: Hey mkopriva, thanks for the answers.I've tried to run the upload by using goroutine and it worked on the local server.But when I test in on the server it waited for upload responses.